# PHP date format for Paypal API PROFILESTARTDATE in CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile

Tags: php, paypal

What PHP date format should I use for PROFILESTARTDATE when calling CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile using the Paypal API?

The Paypal docs say: #Billing date start, in UTC/GMT format

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Couldn't find a good answer anywhere, but this ended up working great. Hope this helps someone!

```
'PROFILESTARTDATE' => gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z")
```